# XPath assertion will always pass in CamelTestSupport class

Tags: java, xpath, assertion

I am new to Camel testing and this test always passes no matter how I change the message. If you could tell me what I am doing wrong I'd much appreciate it.

Here's the assertion:

```
XPathExpression xpath = new XPathExpression("/project/phases/phase/@id='CFA001'");
xpath.setResultType(Boolean.class);     
_resultEndpoint.allMessages().body().matches(xpath);
```

I test it with:

```
_resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
```

I did try various other version, approaches. None of them worked as expected.

The question is, how to make an XPath test on a content (body) of an (expected) XML message

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright...it seems a bit odd to me, but adding:

```
.expectedMessageCount(1);
```

...to the assertion seems to solve the problem. At least the test that suppose to fail , fails. So, here's how the complete assertion should look like:

MockEndpoint as the class member:

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
protected MockEndpoint _resultEndpoint;
```

The assertion:

```
_resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
XPathExpression xpath = new XPathExpression("/project/phases/phase/@id='CFA001'");
xpath.setResultType(Boolean.class);
_resultEndpoint.allMessages().body().matches(xpath);
```